# Need SQL Server Query to solve 3rd Order Polynomial Regression

Tags: sql, math, regression

Can anyone help with some SQL query code to provide estimates of the co-efficients for a 3rd order Polynomial regression?

Please assume that I have a table of X and Y data values and want to estimate a, b and c in:

```
Y(X) = aX + bX^2 + cX^3 + E
```

Comment: It would be helpful, if you could paste the formula for estimation of a, b and c, because, not everybody here is good with mathematics...

Comment: Thanks hochgurgler. Neveed - there are a number of methods for estimating a, b and c. I am just not sure which is best suited to an SQL query so open to guidance. I'm happy to sacrifice accuracy for ease of SQL coding...

Comment: @user1211104: SQL works best with sets of data, so a set-driven method would be best. How many different methods are available? Also, which RDBMS (Oracle, SQLServer, MySQL, etc) are you using?

Comment: @MarkBannister: going off the title, I'd say SQL Server.

Comment: Hi Mark, my data is stored on an SQLServer database. I need to write the SQL in ReportingServices2.0

Comment: The following link has a java script based example of what I need to do with the data in my table http://home.ubalt.edu/ntsbarsh/Business-stat/otherapplets/PolynoReg.htm

Comment: So ... you want us to work out exactly what a Javascript page is doing, then translate it into SQL for you?

Comment: Not neccessarily - my suspicion is that there may be an approach that is more appropriate for implementation in SQL that someone has impletemented before. The Javascript page was an example analysis tool that may be a useful reference.

Answer (score 6):

APPROXIMATE but fast solution would be to sample 4 representative points from the data and solve the polynomial equation for these points.

1. As for the **sampling**, you can split the data into equal sectors and compute average of X and Y for each sector - *the split can be done using quartiles of X-values, averages of X-values, `min(x)+(max(x)-min(x))/4` or whatever you think is the most appropriate*.

   To illustrate the sampling by quartiles *(i.e. by row numbers)*: [image: illustration of solving 3rd order polynomial by sampling 4 points]
2. As for the **solving**, i used [numberempire.com](http://www.numberempire.com/equationsolver.php) to solve these* equations for variables `k,a,b,c`:

   ```
   k + a*X1 + b*X1^2 + c*X1^3 - Y1 = 0,
   k + a*X2 + b*X2^2 + c*X2^3 - Y2 = 0,
   k + a*X3 + b*X3^2 + c*X3^3 - Y3 = 0,
   k + a*X4 + b*X4^2 + c*X4^3 - Y4 = 0
   ```

   *Since `Y(X) =  0 + ax bx^2 + cx^3 + ϵ` implicitly includes [0, 0] point as one of the sample points, it would create bad approximations for data sets that don't include [0, 0]. I took the liberty of solving `Y(X) =  k + ax bx^2 + cx^3 + ϵ` instead.

The actual SQL would go like this:

```
select
    -- returns 1 row with columns labeled K, A, B and C = coefficients in 3rd order polynomial equation for the 4 sample points
    -(X1*(X2p2*(X3p3*Y4-X4p3*Y3)+X2p3*(X4p2*Y3-X3p2*Y4)+(X3p2*X4p3-X3p3*X4p2)*Y2)+X1p2*(X2*(X4p3*Y3-X3p3*Y4)+X2p3*(X3*Y4-X4*Y3)+(X3p3*X4-X3*X4p3)*Y2)+X1p3*(X2*(X3p2*Y4-X4p2*Y3)+X2p2*(X4*Y3-X3*Y4)+(X3*X4p2-X3p2*X4)*Y2)+(X2*(X3p3*X4p2-X3p2*X4p3)+X2p2*(X3*X4p3-X3p3*X4)+X2p3*(X3p2*X4-X3*X4p2))*Y1)/(X1*(X2p2*(X4p3-X3p3)-X3p2*X4p3+X3p3*X4p2+X2p3*(X3p2-X4p2))+X2*(X3p2*X4p3-X3p3*X4p2)+X1p2*(X3*X4p3+X2*(X3p3-X4p3)+X2p3*(X4-X3)-X3p3*X4)+X2p2*(X3p3*X4-X3*X4p3)+X1p3*(X2*(X4p2-X3p2)-X3*X4p2+X3p2*X4+X2p2*(X3-X4))+X2p3*(X3*X4p2-X3p2*X4))  as k,
    (X1p2*(X2p3*(Y4-Y3)-X3p3*Y4+X4p3*Y3+(X3p3-X4p3)*Y2)+X2p2*(X3p3*Y4-X4p3*Y3)+X1p3*(X3p2*Y4+X2p2*(Y3-Y4)-X4p2*Y3+(X4p2-X3p2)*Y2)+X2p3*(X4p2*Y3-X3p2*Y4)+(X3p2*X4p3-X3p3*X4p2)*Y2+(X2p2*(X4p3-X3p3)-X3p2*X4p3+X3p3*X4p2+X2p3*(X3p2-X4p2))*Y1)/(X1*(X2p2*(X4p3-X3p3)-X3p2*X4p3+X3p3*X4p2+X2p3*(X3p2-X4p2))+X2*(X3p2*X4p3-X3p3*X4p2)+X1p2*(X3*X4p3+X2*(X3p3-X4p3)+X2p3*(X4-X3)-X3p3*X4)+X2p2*(X3p3*X4-X3*X4p3)+X1p3*(X2*(X4p2-X3p2)-X3*X4p2+X3p2*X4+X2p2*(X3-X4))+X2p3*(X3*X4p2-X3p2*X4))  as a,
    -(X1*(X2p3*(Y4-Y3)-X3p3*Y4+X4p3*Y3+(X3p3-X4p3)*Y2)+X2*(X3p3*Y4-X4p3*Y3)+X1p3*(X3*Y4+X2*(Y3-Y4)-X4*Y3+(X4-X3)*Y2)+X2p3*(X4*Y3-X3*Y4)+(X3*X4p3-X3p3*X4)*Y2+(X2*(X4p3-X3p3)-X3*X4p3+X3p3*X4+X2p3*(X3-X4))*Y1)/(X1*(X2p2*(X4p3-X3p3)-X3p2*X4p3+X3p3*X4p2+X2p3*(X3p2-X4p2))+X2*(X3p2*X4p3-X3p3*X4p2)+X1p2*(X3*X4p3+X2*(X3p3-X4p3)+X2p3*(X4-X3)-X3p3*X4)+X2p2*(X3p3*X4-X3*X4p3)+X1p3*(X2*(X4p2-X3p2)-X3*X4p2+X3p2*X4+X2p2*(X3-X4))+X2p3*(X3*X4p2-X3p2*X4))  as b,
    (X1*(X2p2*(Y4-Y3)-X3p2*Y4+X4p2*Y3+(X3p2-X4p2)*Y2)+X2*(X3p2*Y4-X4p2*Y3)+X1p2*(X3*Y4+X2*(Y3-Y4)-X4*Y3+(X4-X3)*Y2)+X2p2*(X4*Y3-X3*Y4)+(X3*X4p2-X3p2*X4)*Y2+(X2*(X4p2-X3p2)-X3*X4p2+X3p2*X4+X2p2*(X3-X4))*Y1)/(X1*(X2p2*(X4p3-X3p3)-X3p2*X4p3+X3p3*X4p2+X2p3*(X3p2-X4p2))+X2*(X3p2*X4p3-X3p3*X4p2)+X1p2*(X3*X4p3+X2*(X3p3-X4p3)+X2p3*(X4-X3)-X3p3*X4)+X2p2*(X3p3*X4-X3*X4p3)+X1p3*(X2*(X4p2-X3p2)-X3*X4p2+X3p2*X4+X2p2*(X3-X4))+X2p3*(X3*X4p2-X3p2*X4))  as c
  from (select
      samples.*,
      -- precomputing the powers should give better performance (at least i hope it would)
      power(X1,2) X1p2, power(X2,2) X2p2, power(X3,2) X3p2, power(X4,2) X4p2,
      power(Y1,3) Y1p3, power(Y2,3) Y2p3, power(Y3,3) Y3p3, power(Y4,3) Y4p3
    from (select
        avg(case when sector = 1 then x end) X1,
        avg(case when sector = 2 then x end) X2,
        avg(case when sector = 3 then x end) X3,
        avg(case when sector = 4 then x end) X4,
        avg(case when sector = 1 then y end) Y1,
        avg(case when sector = 2 then y end) Y2,
        avg(case when sector = 3 then y end) Y3,
        avg(case when sector = 4 then y end) Y4
      from (select x, y, 
          -- splitting to sectors 1 - 4 by row number (SQL Server version)
          ceiling(row_number() OVER (ORDER BY x asc) / count(*) * 4) sector
        from original_data
      )
    ) samples
  )
```

According to [developer.mimer.com](http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser200x/), these optional features need to be enabled in SQL Server:

```
T611, "Elementary OLAP operations"
F591, "Derived tables"
```

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server has a built-in ranking function NTILE(n) which will more easily create your sectors.  I replaced:

```
ceiling(row_number() OVER (ORDER BY x asc) / count(*) * 4) sector
```

with:

```
NTILE(4) OVER(ORDER BY x ASC) [sector]
```

I also needed to add several "precomputed powers" to allow for the full column range as selected.  The full list appears below:

```
POWER(samples.X1, 2) AS [X1p2], 
POWER(samples.X1, 3) AS [X1p3], 
POWER(samples.X2, 2) AS [X2p2], 
POWER(samples.X2, 3) AS [X2p3],
POWER(samples.X3, 2) AS [X3p2], 
POWER(samples.X3, 3) AS [X3p3], 
POWER(samples.X4, 2) AS [X4p2],
POWER(samples.X4, 3) AS [X4p3],
POWER(samples.Y1, 3) AS [Y1p3], 
POWER(samples.Y2, 3) AS [Y2p3], 
POWER(samples.Y3, 3) AS [Y3p3], 
POWER(samples.Y4, 3) AS [Y4p3]
```

Overall, great answer by @Aprillion!  Well explained and the numberempire.com h/t was very helpful.